# Utility for different Wine installation for different programs

Tags: linux, wine

I seem to recall that there is a utility that sets up and manages completely different [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/) installations for different programs. People use it primarily for games, so that the necessary tweaks and config options that work well for one game do not interfere with another.

I can't remember the name of it, though, and no amount of searching has reminded me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/) can do this quite well.  It also has a large list of things it will install for you... but I often use it to just do custom installs so that the program will just manage everything I run with wine.

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for [winetricks](https://code.google.com/p/winetricks/).

Answer (score 0):

Winecfg.  Should be fairly self-explanatory to use, but picking the right settings for an app is sometimes more art than science.

Comment: But this is for *each individual* wine installation. Because many of those configuration options can't be set per-program, not to mention the different redistributables (DLLs) you can/cannot install for different programs, there is another tool that manages separate Wine installations to completely isolate them from each other.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question.  There used to be a separate utility program for this, but in recent versions you want to set the `$WINEPREFIX` environment variable to the name of the directory where wine stores its data.  Defaults to `$HOME/.wine`.

Comment: Ah, that's a useful trick :) I'm **positive** that there's a thing to manage all of this... it's infuriating...